How do i make it go back after typing for example 1
int prikaz;
        while (prikaz != 0) {
            System.out.print("Co chceš udělat? ");
            

            switch (prikaz) {
                case 1:
                    Predmet predmet = hrac.getAktualniMistnost().getPredmety().stream()
                            .filter(i -> i.getJmeno().equals("mapa"))
                            .findFirst()
                            .orElse(null);

                    if (predmet != null) {
                        hrac.pridatPredmet(predmet);
                        hrac.getAktualniMistnost().getPredmety().remove(predmet);
                        System.out.println("Vzal jsem si tu mapu.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Mapa není v místnosti.");
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    if (hrac.getInventar().stream().noneMatch(i -> i.getJmeno().equals("mapa"))) {
                        System.out.println("Nemůžeš opustit místnost bez mapy.");
                    } else {
                        Mistnost nextMistnost = hrac.getAktualniMistnost().getSoused().stream()
                                .filter(room -> room.getJmeno().equals("m2"))
                                .findFirst()
                                .orElse(null);

                        if (nextMistnost != null) {
                            hrac.setAktualniMistnost(nextMistnost);
                            System.out.println("Odejíždíš do " + nextMistnost.getJmeno() + ".");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Nemůžeš opustit místnost.");
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Hra ukončena.");
                    return;  // Ukončení hry
                default:
                    System.out.println("Neznámý příkaz.");
                    break;
            }
        }

So foe example a type 1 and the code goes how it should but after the action it stops. But i dont want that, i want it to go back to the "Co chceš udělat?". The code wants me to add int prikaz=0;, but that doesnt help either please help

Where are you (ever) assigning a value to prikaz ?  I assume that you are supposed to read a "prikaz" value entered by the user, but you are not doing that.
